# Define variable error

Tags: vba, excel, variables, numbers

I am creating a packing slip on the packing slip sheet. All of my buttons are on packing slip. I have an order number in cell O5 that needs to be defined as PNUM.
PNUM compares to ONUM which is defined to look at each variable in the order header sheet and copy the appropriate client the package is being shipped to.

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim PNUM As Long
    Dim ONUM As Long
    Dim c As Integer
    c = 17



    For I = 295 To 300
        PNUM = Sheets("Packing Slip").Cells(15, 5)
        ONUM = Sheets("Order Header").Cells(I, 1)

        MsgBox (PNUM)
        MsgBox (ONUM)

        If PNUM = ONUM Then

                Worksheets("Packing Slip").Cells(c, 2) = Worksheets("Order Header").Cells(I, 2)
                Worksheets("Packing Slip").Cells(c, 11) = Worksheets("Order Header").Cells(I, 3)
                Worksheets("Packing Slip").Cells(c, 6) = Worksheets("Order Header").Cells(I, 4)

            End If
    Next I
```

For some reason my message box for PNUM is always 0, not the value entered.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help!!

Comment: put another msgbox in: `MsgBox Sheets("Packing Slip").Cells(15, 5)` and see what it returns, my guess you are pointing at the wrong cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
PNUM = Sheets("Packing Slip").Cells(15, 5)
```

Like this:

```
PNUM = Worksheets("Packing Slip").Range("E15")
```

If it works, you are mistaking rows and columns.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something little I was just in too far to see it from that perspective. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

As [Vityata correctly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45940991/1188513), you're inverting rows and columns in your `.Cells` call.

That's an easy trap to fall into, because you're working with late-bound calls against an `Object` and thus, don't get IntelliSense tooltips to tell you what the expected parameters are as you type them.

The solution is to work with early-bound calls against a `Worksheet`. Declare a local variable:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Packing Slip")
```

And now the `.Cells` calls you do against that `sheet` variable *will* provide you with IntelliSense tooltips and you'll never make that mistake again!